# Unable to pull image from JFrog docker registery

Tags: docker, kubernetes, artifactory

I'm using JFrog repository as my private jfog repo. And I have specified the secret in order to authenticate it. The pod fails with an ImagePullBackOff error, when I describe the pod I see

> Failed to pull image "private_registry/image_name": rpc error: code =
> Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image
> "private_registry/image_name": failed to do request: Head
> `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:port-number/v2/<docker-registryname>/<application-name>/manifests/<tag>:`
> http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client   Warning  Failed
> 23m (x4 over 24m)     kubelet, worker01  Error: ErrImagePull

when I pull the same image using docker pull  , the image get pulled successfully

Comment: how does the SSL work for `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:port-number`? did you add something in the docker config for `docker pull`?

Answer (score 0):

While having the HTTP server communicating with the HTTPS server (probably due to the usage of a self-signed certificate) being the private registry, registering the concerned registry as an insecure registry with the docker client could resolve the docker error.

```
{ "insecure-registries":["IP:PORT"] }
```

An entry similar to the above need to be included in the /etc/docker/daemon.json file and considering the environment to be in K8s, it needs to be configured on all the nodes.